# Problems with JFrame: it shows a list of number instead of the image

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I wanted to try to use `JFrame` and I tried with many code-examples on Internet and on video tutorial (like the one below).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        //1. Create the frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

        //2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //3. Create components and put them in the frame.
        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("BLAHBLAHBHALBAHLKKDJF");
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //4. Size the frame.
        frame.pack();

        //5. Show it.
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Eclipse doesn't show me any error in the code but when I run it frame always show me the image below (a list of numbers). And I totally don't understand why.

On the run button in Eclipse appear in yellow the writing "Run AnnotatedMemoryPanel".

I don't find any discussion on internet about this.
Hope someone could explain me what is wrong.

[image]

Comment: I solved. The problem was that i run AnnotatedMemoryPanel. The right procedure is run as a "java application". Incredible how i spent almost 1 day for this stupid thing. Maybe writing the problem on forum helped me understanding it -.- Maybe will help someone else

Comment: Cool. I tried. it works well. Keep going :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running some completely different application by accident, not the one you posted the source code for. In Eclipse try right clicking the source code, then select `Run As`, then `Java Application`. The shortcut for this is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>.